# What are the guarantees for long lived Azure and Azure.Authenticated clients in the Azure java sdk?

Tags: java, azure, azure-sdk

Currently I am creating `Azure` and `Azure.Authenticated` clients in my application. Since my application is long lived and could be running for months, what guarantees can I expect from the clients. Once they are created can they be used indefinitely, or are there some tokens behind the scenes that have to be refreshed? Also are there any network connections that they create that could be lost and require the client to be recreated?

Comment: if possible do add the type of application like app service , azure batch etc. and what type of clients - android app where the user login or the token has a very long expiry etc.. and which flow are you looking at having this scenario etc. basically elaborate it so that more users can try sharing their thoughts.

Comment: Maybe you are searching for [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview)?